# Cast MethodBase to RuntimeMethodInfo in F#

Tags: reflection, f#

I want to cast MethodBase to RuntimeMethodInfo in order to retrieve the name and type of the arguments of reflected methods, and the returned type of those methods.

I can make a direct cast in Inmediate Window but have not found a way to make the cast with F#.

Comment: What version of .NET? [`RuntimeMethodInfo` is `internal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs) in 4.5.1.

Comment: .NET 3.5 so far, but if I have searched correctly, it is also internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why cast?  You can call GetParameters() and all the other members you'd need on the MethodBase reference.

```
let methodInfo : MethodBase = //whatever
let firstParamName = methodInfo.GetParameters().[0].Name
```

EDIT (return types):

First, note that GetMethod returns MethodInfo, not MethodBase.  You can't cast to RuntimeMethodInfo since, as others have noted, that is an internal type.  But the `ReturnType` property is declared on MethodInfo, so all is well.

This therefore works, with the static type of methodInfo being MethodInfo:

```
let methodInfo = typeof<object>.GetMethod("ToString")
let returnTypeName = methodInfo.ReturnType.Name // "String"
```

Second, if you have a static reference to a MethodBase that you know is a MethodInfo, use the `:?>` operator.  Example:

```
let toMethodInfo (mb : MethodBase) = mb :?> MethodInfo
```

On the other hand, if you're not sure about the object's actual type, you can use `match`:

```
let tryToMethodInfo (mb : MethodBase) =
    match mb with
    | :? MethodInfo as result -> Some result
    | _ -> None
```

Finally, since you ask about "vice versa" in your comment:  When you're going from a derived class to one of its base classes, which always succeeds, you don't need the question mark:

```
let toMethodBase (mi : MethodInfo) = mi :> MethodBase
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but, How do you get "returned type of those methods" from MethodBase?

Comment: I should have asked for cast from MethodBase to MethodInfo and viceversa.

Comment: @jruizaranguren see edited post for more information.